# Write a line into a .txt file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to use Node.js to create a simple logging system which prints a line before the past line into a .txt file. However, I don't know how the file system functionality from Node.js works.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: So, you want to insert a line into the middle of a text file, right? It'll be much easier to append strings to the end.

Comment: Yes, ok how can i append a string at the end ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append to a file in Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node)

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Inserting data into the middle of a text file is not a simple task. If possible, you should append it to the end of your file.

The easiest way to append data some text file  is to use build-in [`fs.appendFile(filename, data[, options], callback)` function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback) from [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.appendFile('log.txt', 'new data', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // append failed
  } else {
    // done
  }
})
```

But if you want to write data to log file several times, then it'll be best to use [`fs.createWriteStream(path[, options])` function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) instead:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', {
  flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
})

logger.write('some data') // append string to your file
logger.write('more data') // again
logger.write('and more') // again
```

Node will keep appending new data to your file every time you'll call `.write`, until your application will be closed, or until you'll manually close the stream calling `.end`:

```
logger.end() // close string
```

Note that `logger.write` in the above example does not write to a new line. To write data to a new line:

```
var writeLine = (line) => logger.write(`\n${line}`);
writeLine('Data written to a new line');
```

Comment: It is necessary to save the file ? If i use fs.appendFile, the file is still empty ?

Comment: `appendFile` will open text file, append new data to it, and save it afterwards. So, no, you don't need to save it yourself. It your file is empty, try checking `err` in `appendFile` callback.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning both one time and multiple time options.

Comment: does `write` put a new line?

Comment: Why is logger.write (for second example) consuming large heap space while writing a huge file?

Comment: This answer was for me helpful too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61890003/12305715

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `fs` module and something like this:

```
fs.appendFile('server.log', 'string to append', function (err) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   console.log('Appended!');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**

If you have a small file
Read all the file data in to memory

**Step 2**

Convert file data string into Array

**Step 3**

Search the array to find a location where you want to insert the text

**Step 4**

Once you have the location insert your text

```
yourArray.splice(index,0,"new added test");
```

**Step 5**

convert your array to string

```
yourArray.join("");
```

**Step 6**

write your file like so

```
fs.createWriteStream(yourArray);
```

This is not advised if your file is too big

Answer (score 3):

I created a log file which prints data into text file using "Winston" logger. The source code is here below,

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
var fs = require('fs')
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('Data Log.txt', {
  flags: 'a' 
})
const os = require('os');
var sleep = require('system-sleep');
var endOfLine = require('os').EOL;
var t = '             ';
var s = '         ';
var q = '               ';
var array1=[];
var array2=[];
var array3=[];
var array4=[];
              
array1[0]  =  78;
array1[1]  =  56;
array1[2]  =  24;
array1[3]  =  34;
                  
for (var n=0;n<4;n++)
{
  array2[n]=array1[n].toString();
}
                 
for (var k=0;k<4;k++)
{
  array3[k]=Buffer.from('                    ');
}

for (var a=0;a<4;a++)  
{
  array4[a]=Buffer.from(array2[a]);
}

for (m=0;m<4;m++)
{
  array4[m].copy(array3[m],0);
}

logger.write('Date'+q);
logger.write('Time'+(q+'  '))
logger.write('Data 01'+t);
logger.write('Data 02'+t); 
logger.write('Data 03'+t);
logger.write('Data 04'+t)

logger.write(endOfLine);
logger.write(endOfLine);

function mydata()      //user defined function
{
  logger.write(datechar+s);
  logger.write(timechar+s);
  for ( n = 0; n < 4; n++) 
  {
   logger.write(array3[n]);
  }
  logger.write(endOfLine); 
}

var now = new Date();
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var date = dateFormat(now,"isoDate");
var time = dateFormat(now, "h:MM:ss TT ");
var datechar = date.toString();
var timechar = time.toString();
mydata();
sleep(5*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js can use streams to read data from a source and write data to a source.

Instead of read the entire contents of a file and storing it in RAM, hogging memory resources, use a stream. A stream processes data sequentially, "piece by piece", instead of all at once.

Use the fs node core module for creating a writeable stream.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const writeInterface = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/myTextFile.txt`, {
  flags: "a",
});

const shoppingList = [
  "dozen organic eggs",
  "oat milk",
  "cane sugar",
  "sushi rice",
  "nori",
  "sesame seeds",
  "soy sauce",
  "rice vinegar",
  "coffee",
];

shoppingList.forEach((item) => writeInterface.write(`${item}\n`));

// indicate the end of the of the writeStream with the end method
writeInterface.end();
```

Now the contents of myTextFile.txt are:

```
dozen organic eggs
oat milk
cane sugar
sushi rice
nori
sesame seeds
soy sauce
rice vinegar
coffee
```