# Create a text file using JavaScript without using web interface

Tags: javascript, text-files

I'm looking for a method to create + write a text file using JavaScript but I only found method with browser. I don't need my browser to do that, I want to implement a method in my code that write data in a text file nothing to do with the browser.

So someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean using node.js?

Comment: There are dozens of tools that execute JavaScript without using a browser. You're question boils down to asking for a recommendation for which tool to use to run the JS. Shopping questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin I don't really understand your first sentence I mean why you tell me that but I agree that maybe it's off-topic

Comment: @emiliopedrollo yes I use Node.js so I'll look into it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js this question answer perfectly about my problem. I think @emiliopedrollo you should put an answer because I have find it with your hint about node.js

Comment: @Jerome you could accept Andrew Monks answer as he already did one that points to the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Node.Js:

[Node.js Write a line into a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418777/node-js-write-a-line-into-a-txt-file)

Something like:

```
var fs = require('fs')

var logger = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', {
  flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
})

logger.write('some data') // append string to your file
logger.write('more data') // again
logger.write('and more') // again
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15143143)

Comment: Amended my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you it's better now ! Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks.  This helps understand the answer much better.