# How to output a consoles log to another file as regular text

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to print the result of my console.log to another .txt file, how would I make this happen? this is what my console.log looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYY00.jpg

I'm wanting this printed as regular text to an output file e.g 'output.txt'

Comment: You could do basically this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: @AustinFrench I'm not using any html in my program - i want to type something into my terminal and have it output to another file

Comment: I get that, So I don't see this as a duplicate but the concept would be the same: Allocate memory, out stuff in it, open a stream and download. I don't have the energy right now to hack it, so perhaps you can or another answerer will

Comment: thats fine, thanks anyways @AustinFrench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) to achieve this.
You can set up [Winston Transports](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport) to output in file `winston.add(winston.transports.File, options)`

Or if you don't wanna add any npm modules to your app you can just do this

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(text) {
  fs.appendFile('output.txt', text + '\n', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
};
```

And save this to a file in your project directory, for example NameOfYourFile.js.

Then you can just require it in a file that you wanna make output from

```
var loger = require('./NameOfYourFile');

loger('Logs');
loger('Output');
loger('Working');
```

And just use loger instead of console.log. You also can easily rename it.

TypeScript version

First, install node modules

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Then create a file for your module, for example, NameOfYourFile.ts

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
export default function(text) {
  fs.appendFile('output.txt', text + '\n', function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
 });
};
```

Then you can import it like this

```
import loger from './NameOfYourFile';

loger('Logs');
loger('Output');
loger('Working');
```

Comment: I'm using typescript @Vitaly - it has to be made into a module but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I also want to add I'm trying to get this done with fs

Comment: But my second solution is a module and it using fs

Comment: I know that its a module but modules work differently in typescript @Vitaly

Comment: I add typescript version to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you rewrite your program as a node app and then just run it from the Terminal window instead? Then, you wouldn't need to wrestle with this problem of getting your console output into a file... you could use node's fs instead ([Node.js Write a line into a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418777/node-js-write-a-line-into-a-txt-file))

Comment: It is a node app, and I am already using node's fs already.
I'm asking how would I use it to log it to another file. the question you linked asked how to send a string to another file, I want to send a console.log's results

Answer (score 0):

This answer works, but it isn't what i'm aiming for it will work for most other people i'd assume. you're gonna want to run your program like so:

```
npm start > output.txt
```

this will print your console output to the output.txt file I still need to achieve this with node fs so i'd appreciate anymore answers