# How to append to second last line in a file in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to append to second last line of a file using NodeJs!

I hope I am making sense.

Thanks in advance

My current code which appends to end of the file:

```
fs.appendFile('data.txt', 'something', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Comment: There's a lot to cover here, please may you show us what you've already got using a [mcve]? We can't just give you a solution.

Comment: Ofcourse, I have added my current working code which appends text to the end of the file @evolutionxbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write a line into a .txt file with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418777/write-a-line-into-a-txt-file-with-node-js)

Comment: if your file is not too huge, you can read it in ram with fs.readFile. then you can loop from the end of the resulting buffer to find \n. then insert data at this position. then save the file on the disk.