# How to grab data from JSON in CoffeeScript?

Tags: json, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract specific data from JSON using CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007234/how-to-extract-specific-data-from-json-using-coffeescript)

I want to grab a specific piece of data from a massive JSON string. The entire string would be more than 10 pages long if posted here, so I'm just including an example snippet:

```
   { name: '',
     keys:
      [ 'statType',
        'count',
        'dataVersion',
        'value',
        'championId',
        'futureData' ],
     object:
      { statType: 'TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED',
        count: { value: 5 },
        dataVersion: 0,
        value: { value: 5 },
        championId: { value: 31 },
        futureData: null },
     encoding: 0 }
```

How can I use CoffeeScript to:

1. parse that string to locate the object with a specific value, such as `TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED`,
2. take the numerical value from that object (the `value` field), and
3. ideally, append that value into an external text file?

I am pretty much a super noob programmer. Basically, how could I, in this example, take that `5` value from the object labelled `TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED`, and append it into a text file using CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whether you're doing this in the [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON) or in [Node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726756/659910), you should be able to pass the JSON string to JSON.parse and pick out the value you want. You can then append to a file using Node's fs module like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267583/659910.

```
fs = require 'fs'

# Sample JSON string.
json = '{ "statType": "TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED", "count": { "value": 5 }, "dataVersion": 0 }'

data = JSON.parse(json)
fs.appendFile('/tmp/data.txt', data.count.value, (error) -> throw error if error)
```