# How get string pathname?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How get string pathname ?

```
var http=require('http');
var url = require("url");
http.createServer(function(req,res){


var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");



res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello\n');
}).listen(8124,'127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server me!');
```

There is no error output,but not displayed Request for ....

Comment: See this post for logging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
FL261:~ jvah$ node pathname
Server me!
Request for / received.
```

And at the same time in the other window using curl:

```
FL261:~ jvah$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8124/
Hello
```