# writeFile is only writing one statement/log

Tags: javascript, writefile

```
function querydb() {
  cursor = dbConnection.collection("logs").find(queryObj).limit(parseInt(valueList[1]));

  /*Either decide here to foreach for file or for console OR...*/
  cursor.forEach(function(item) {
    /*Decide here whether to write to file or console*/
    if (valueList[0] != null) {
      fs.writeFile(valueList[0], JSON.stringify(item), 'utf-8', console.log("finished!!"));
    }
    if (valueList[0] == null) {
      console.log(item);
      console.log("Done");
    }

    /*CHECK TO SEE IF THE CURSOR IS EXHAUSTED*/
    if (cursor == null) {
      //now we can close the database
      dbConnection.close();
    }
  });
};
```

I call writeFile in my querydb function. I don't understand why its not writing all the logs I'm calling instead its just writing one log to my txt file.

Comment: thanks for that, but do you know whats going on with my code?

Comment: does anyone know whats going on. please im stuck at this issue.

Comment: beacuse fs.writeFile overwrite your previous data, try `fs.appendFile`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node