# Can't write/append to JSON file in Node Webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

I want to have persistent memory (store the user's progress) in a .json file in %AppData%. I tried doing this according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093042/how-do-i-add-to-an-existing-json-file-in-node-js?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, but it doesn't work. For testing purposes I'm only working with storing one object.

The code below doesn't work at all. If I use `fs.open(filePath, "w", function(err, data) { ...` instead of `readFile(...`, it does create a json file in %AppData%, but then it doesn't write anything to it, it's always 0 bytes.

```
var nw = require('nw.gui');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var file = "userdata.json";

var filePath = path.join(nw.App.dataPath, file);

console.log(filePath); // <- This shows correct path in Application Data.

fs.readFile(filePath ,function (err, data) {
var idVar = "1";
var json = JSON.parse(data);
json.push("id :" + idVar);
fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

If anyone has any idea where I'm messing this up, I'd be grateful..

**EDIT:**

Solved, thanks to kailniris.

I was simply trying to parse an empty file

Comment: Check out the background page console for errors. Node context errors will be logged there. Right click on the window then inspect background page.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Which line? There is something wrong with your json or you want to parse an empty data as json. Console.log(data) before parse

Comment: It was "var json = JSON.parse(data);". Yes, obviously it was empty. Thank you very much, now it works fine. On a side note, is there a way to work around this? There has to be a first entry, after all.

Comment: well yea, check if it's empty before you try to parse it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no json in the file you try to read. Before parsing data check if the file is empty. If it is then create an empty json, push the new data into it then write it to the file else parse the json in the file.