# Add object to JSON with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON file that I need to use as a database to add, remove and modify users, I have this code:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let student = {  
    id: 15,
    nombre: 'TestNombre', 
    apellido: 'TestApellido',
    email: 'TestEmail@gmail.com',
    confirmado: true 
};


let data = JSON.stringify(student, null, 2);
fs.writeFileSync('personas.json', data);
```

But that overwrites the JSON file, and I need to append as another object, so it continues with id 15 (last one was 14).

Here is a piece of the JSON file:

```
{
  "personas": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "nombre": "Aurelia",
      "apellido": "Osborn",
      "email": "aureliaosborn@lovepad.com",
      "confirmado": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Curry",
      "apellido": "Jefferson",
      "email": "curryjefferson@lovepad.com",
      "confirmado": true
    },
  ]
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Load the file first, keep it in memory and everytime you update that object you also store it back in the file.

Comment: There are some nice node_modules that can do the fs stuff for you and make it seem like you are just dealing with data. One that comes to mind is [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb).

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093042/how-do-i-add-to-an-existing-json-file-in-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `require` the file, push the `student` in the `personas` prop and 
`writeFileSync` it back.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let current = require('./personas.json');
let student = {
    id: 15,
    nombre: 'TestNombre',
    apellido: 'TestApellido',
    email: 'TestEmail@gmail.com',
    confirmado: true
};

current.personas.push(student);

// Make sure you stringify it using 4 spaces of identation
// so it stays human-readable.
fs.writeFileSync('personas.json', JSON.stringify(current, null, 4));
```

Comment: why the sync? just curious

Comment: To match the OP's preferred method. He/She already uses `fs. writeFileSync` in the question code snippet.

Comment: ah! ok, thought maybe it was really necesary :P

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

every time you want to write to the JSON file, you’ll need to read it first/parse it, update he Object and then write it to disk.

There’s a popular solution already handling that. Checkout [lowdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lowdb)

For the autoindexing - I believe the documentation suggests ways some helper libraries for this module to make that happen

Don’t reinvent the wheel!