# How to stop a file from beign overwritten with fs.writefile

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The problem is that when I am trying to save data that I get from a chat room that is made with socket.io in nodejs, the file keeps getting overwritten once the user has submitted their message to the chatroom. However I want the user name + message to be added to the file instead of overwriting it, so both the username and the message will get stored in to the JSON file as a object.

This is what i tried at first:

```js
socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message',{ message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
var collect = {
  message: message,
  name: users[socket.id] 
 }
  var savechatData = JSON.stringify(collect)
  fs.writeFile('./public/static/chattingdata/chat.json', savechatData, function (error) {
  if (error) {
  console.log("There has been an error saving your configuration data")
  console.log(error.message)
  return
  }
  console.log('Configuration saved succesfully')
  })
})
})
```

But that would just overwrite it. So then i tried like this:

```js
socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message',{ message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
var collect = {
  message: message,
  name: users[socket.id] 
 }
  var savechatData = JSON.stringify(collect)
  fs.writeFile('./public/static/chattingdata/chat.json', {'flags': 'a'}, savechatData, function (error) {
  if (error) {
  console.log("There has been an error saving your configuration data")
  console.log(error.message)
  return
  }
  console.log('Configuration saved succesfully')
  })
})
})
```

But then i get the error: 'ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING'

So how could i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`fs.writeFile` function's signature is `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`. The data parameter should be given as the second parameter and the optional options parameter as the third parameter. [Refer Docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Change your code from

```
fs.writeFile('./public/static/chattingdata/chat.json', {'flags': 'a'}, savechatData, function (error){ // Callback })
```

to

```
fs.writeFile('./public/static/chattingdata/chat.json', savechatData, {'flags': 'a'}, function (error) { // callback })
```

Comment: This works but it still seems to overwrite the file. I have found that people said i have to use the flag a+ but this also overwrites the file. Which i dont want, because i want to add a new line to the file and not overwrite it.

Comment: @SpringerJerry Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093042/how-do-i-add-to-an-existing-json-file-in-node-js). They have asked to open the file first using `json.parse()`, then append the data to the file and lastly save the file again.