# Insert new JSON data to the json file using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs and I have a json file named as

```
users.json
```

now I have a endpoint that will insert the json data to the file, now I want to insert the new json data.

for example:

when first time I call the endpoint:

```
http://localhost:3000/users

{
    "user":"john"
}
```

file should be like this:

```
[{"user":"john"}]
```

and when I again call the endpoint like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users

{
    "user":"chris"
}
```

It should add this new data like this:

```
[{"user":"john"},{"user":"chris"}]
```

what I have tried:

```
app.post('/users',(req, res) => {
   let data = req.body
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
     fs.readFile('users.json', 'utf8',function(err, data) {
                let usersJsonData = JSON.parse(data)
                usersJsonData.push(jsonData)
                fs.writeFile("users.json", JSON.stringify(usersJsonData), (err, result)=> {
                    if(err){ 
                        console.log('error', err)
                    } else{
                        res.send({
                            "sucess" : true
                        })
                    };
                })
                // console.log("data", JSON.parse(data))
            })
 })
```

but problem with this method is it inserting data like this:

```
   ["{\"user\":\"wick\"}","{\"user\":\"john\"}"]
```

and I want like this:

```
[{"user":"john"},{"user":"chris"}]
```

Comment: You need to [parse the existing file, add to the array, then write the entire file back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093141/476).

Comment: @deceze I edit my question can you please check ?

Comment: You're stringifying your data twice, that's why.