# Append text to a local text file with JavaScript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, file, text, local

I'm a beginner, and I'm just doing something for fun. Does anyone know how I can append data to a local text file on the server side? I would rather use JavaScript, but I can use PHP, and it would be perfect if I could call the function like this:

```
appendData(data, fileName);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? How do you run the code in the server-side?

Comment: http://php.net/fopen http://php.net/fwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is huge you may not want to go the file_get_contents route (since it has to read the entire file and then write it out. You could do:

```
$fp = fopen($filename,"a");
fwrite($fp,$data);
```

"a" positions the pointer at the end for appending. If you don't mind cheating:

```
`echo $data >> $filename`;
```

which escapes to the shell.

Comment: And if `$data` has the string `>>` ?

Comment: the shell method can be problematic if non alpha characters are possible. You can enclose in quotes; but you can still have issues with $ or [] or other special shell characters.

Comment: A backslash before those special chars would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a PHP server, you can do something like this in php:

```
file_put_contents("/path/to/file", file_get_contents("/path/to/file") . $data);
```

You can't do this with browser JavaScript directly. This is because browser javascript runs on the browser and not on the server.

If you're running a node.js server (which is a JavaScript server and is different from JavaScript running on a browser) you can do something like below. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267583/3006989) answer.

```
var fs = require("fs"); // Get file system
fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', function (err) {

});
```