# Write in a file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know if it's possible to write in a file in multiple rows.

I wrote this snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs');

for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
   fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', i, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

But I'm seeing only one row written in the file. How can I write in 10 rows with the for loop?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append to a file in Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node)

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález it still write in an entire row

Comment: Linefeed problem then. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add multiple lines, you need to append the linefeed character:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = "";
for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
    str += i + "\r\n"; // Linefeed \r\n usually on Windows and \n only on Linux
}
// Only one filewrite, to optimize
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', str, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

If you want to append it doing multiple filewrites because of reasons, you will also need the linefeed character.

```
var fs = require('fs');
for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
    fs.appendFile('helloworld.txt', i + "\r\n", function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Protip: The key here is the linefeed character/s.

Protip 2: Keep your indentation clean.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
 var data= [{ link:"localhost",text:"hello world"}];
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
    stream.once('open', function() {
      stream.write('Link, Text\n');
      data.forEach(function(row) {stream.write(row.link+','+row.text+'\n')});
      console.log("Please Check YourFile!")
      stream.end();
    });
```