# Can an Angular application modify local files?

Tags: json, angular, local

I am developing an application in Angular 4 that uses data and different parameters from a json file that will be at the source of the project. Changes to these parameters will be made in this application and the file must therefore be modified. Is this possible or does Angular not allow to modify the file locally?

Comment: JS can not write to / modify the filesystem.

Comment: Yet "fs.appendFile" allows to do it no?

Comment: Well the best I could find was this (regarding fs.appendFile): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa