# Post data in local file without replacing existing data

Tags: node.js, api

Here is my code which will get data from the postman and write to a file but while writing it replacing the existing data how to fix that in this code.

```
app.post('/postUser', function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());

        fs.writeFile('test.json', data, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("Finished writing")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My output should be like this.

```
[
  {
    "name":"Alpha",
    "password":"123",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name":"beta",
    "password":"123",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

When I use appendFile I am getting output like this :

```
[
    {
        "name": "alpha",
        "password": "123",
        "id": 4
    }
]  {
        "name": "sdad",
        "password": "123",
        "id": 4
    }
```

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node#11267583

Comment: I need output like i mentioned this like shows to append if i use append it printing the data like this  [
  {
    "name":"Alpha",
    "password":"123",
    "id": 1
  } ]
  {
    "name":"beta",
    "password":"123",
    "id": 2
  }

Comment: Please see my potential solution below then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post("/postUser", function(req, res) {
    req.on("data", function(data) {
        var newData;

        fs.readFile("test.json", function(readErr, fileData) {
            if (readErr) {
                console.error(readErr);
            }
            newData = JSON.parse(fileData).push(data);

            fs.writeFile("test.json", newData, function(writeErr) { 
                if (writeErr) {
                    console.error(writeErr);
                }
                console.log("Finished writing!");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The way I usually get around this problem is to read the existing data and then append *(`push`)* your new data to the existing and write the result

Comment: How to do this with post method

Comment: TypeError: fileData.push is not a function getting this error

Comment: You most likely need to parse the result using `JSON.parse()`. I will update my answer. What is the value of `fileData` before you mutate it?

Comment: [
  {
    "name":"Alpha",
    "password":"123",
    "id": 1
  }]

Comment: I need this to be completed can you help me in private

Comment: If you use the `JSON.parse()` function I have mentioned in my answer, it should work

Comment: Yea i used now in my json file its printing 2 instead of data

Comment: Brilliant :) so is that fixed now?

Comment: But i need data bro as i mentioned in the question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182148/discussion-between-wmash-and-dark-ninja).

Comment: check the chat dood

Answer (score 0):

The `writeFile` method will just replace the data if any present in the file or will create a file if not exists and write data to it.

Instead of fs.writFile use the `appendFile` method to append any data to the file.

```
app.post('/postUser', function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());

        fs.appendFile('test.json', data, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("Finished writing")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: But see my output in my question for the append file i am getting data outside the array

Answer (score 0):

First read the file and append it with your changes and write it again.

```
app.post('/postUser', function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function(err, file){
            //handle error
            if(!file) {
                var file = '';
            }
            var temp = JSON.parse(file);
            temp.push(data);    
            fs.writeFile('test.json', temp, function (err) {
                //handle error
                console.log("FILE STORED")
            });
        })
    });
});
```