# Print console errors (with response code 4xx or 5xx) in logger file in protractor automation

Tags: protractor

I want to print console error with response code 4xx or 5xx in a logger file while executing automation script in protractor. Now I am using the following code in my afterEach. It prints everything from the console.

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
   console.log('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thr protractor tests, are executed over node, so you can use node's file system ('fs' module) commands.

for example the appendFile methode
[How to append to a file in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node)