# Append JSON to a file using node streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stream, node-streams

Based on what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43370201/1252748), I'm using `fs.createWriteStream` to write some JSON to a file. I am processing the data in chunks of about 50. So at the beginning of the script, I open my streamand then use a function to pass it in, along with some JSON, which is working pretty well for writing.

```
const myStream = fs.createWriteStream(
  path.join(RESULTS_DIR, `my-file.json`),
  {
    flags: 'a'
  }
)


function appendJsonToFile(stream, jsonToAppend) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      stream.write(JSON.stringify(jsonToAppend, null, 2)
      resolve('STREAM_WRITE_SUCCESS')
    } catch (streamError) {
      reject('STREAM_WRITE_FAILURE', streamError)
    }
  })
}

appendJsonToFile(myStream, someJson)
```

However, because each piece of data to be written is an array of objects, the structure I eventually get in my file will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "data": "test data 1",
    },
        {
        "data": "test data 2",
    }
][
    {
        "data": "test data 3",
    },
        {
        "data": "test data 4",
    }
]
```

#### How can I append these pieces of data so that the result is properly formatted JSON, rather than just a series of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is always formatted as you say above the three things you'd need to do are:

1. Find out the current length of the file and substract 2 chars (`\n]`, since there's no newline at end),
2. Remove the first char of the JSON you're saving,
3. Save the file using `r+` mode and with `start`
4. End the stream after each save.

Here's the link to [createWriteStream options](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).

Now the other thing is point 4 makes this rather inefficient and questions the whole idea if streaming should be used here. I think it does make sense, but the question here is if you need the file to be readable between writes - if not then you should use a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_transform_options) in the middle and add flush in between the files and after all work is done (`beforeExit`) you simply end the stream.

You can do this by definition, but I'm the author of a framework called [scramjet](https://www.scramjet.org/) which makes these cases much easier:

```
const myStream = new scramjet.DataStream();

const file = path.join(RESULTS_DIR, `my-file.json`)
const start = fs.statSync(file).size - 2;

myStream
    .flatten()
    .toJSONArray()
    .shift(1)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(
        file,
        {flags: 'r+', start}
    ));

function appendJsonToFile(stream, jsonToAppend) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            stream.write(jsonToAppend)
            resolve('STREAM_WRITE_SUCCESS')
        } catch (streamError) {
            reject('STREAM_WRITE_FAILURE', streamError)
        }
    })
}

appendJsonToFile(myStream, someJson)

process.on('beforeExit', myStream.end());
```

You can use this as above, but if you'd prefer to work on this with plain node streams this should nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: This is really great! Can you show an example using the transform/flush.

Answer (score 1):

I'll resolved the code, with Error and FILE NOT FOUND handler. Solution derived from Michał Karpacki.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const getFolderPath = () => __dirname || process.cwd();
const getFilePath = (fileName) => path.join(getFolderPath(), `${fileName}`);

/**
 * @param {string} fileName - Included File Name & its Extension
 * @param {Array<*>} arrayData
 * @return {Promise<*>}
 */
const writeFileAsync = async (fileName, arrayData) => {
    const filePath = getFilePath(fileName);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const _WritableStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {flags: 'r+', start: fs.statSync(filePath).size - 2});
            _WritableStream.write(JSON.stringify(arrayData, null, 2).replace(/\[/, ','), (streamError) => {
                return reject(['STREAM_WRITE_FAILURE', streamError]);
            });
            return resolve('STREAM_WRITE_SUCCESS');
        } catch (streamError) {
            /** ERROR NOT FOUND SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY !*/
            if (streamError.code === 'ENOENT') {
                fs.mkdirSync(getFolderPath(), {recursive: true});
                return resolve(fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(
                    Array.from({...arrayData, length: arrayData.length}), null, 2
                )));
            }
            /** ERROR OUT OF BOUND TO FILE SIZE RANGE - INVALID START POSITION FOR WRITE STREAM !*/
            if (streamError instanceof RangeError) {
                console.error(`> [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE] =>`, streamError);
                const _WritableStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {flags: 'r+'});
                return resolve(_WritableStream.write(JSON.stringify(arrayData, null, 2), (streamError) => {
                    return reject(['STREAM_WRITE_FAILURE', streamError]);
                }));
            }
            return reject(['STREAM_WRITE_FAILURE', streamError]);
        }
    });
};

(() => writeFileAsync('test1.json',
    [{
        key: "value 1"
    }, {
        key: "value 2"
    }]
))();

/* Output after 1st time run =>
[
  {
    "key": "value 1"
  },
  {
    "key": "value 2"
  }
]
*/
/* Output after 2nd time run => 
[
  {
    "key": "value 1"
  },
  {
    "key": "value 2"
  },
  {
    "key": "value 1"
  },
  {
    "key": "value 2"
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.