# Node fs.writefile \n not adding text to new line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a log file in which I'm adding text.

Here is the code:

```
function appendText(text) { 
    fs.writeFile('file.log', text+'\n',  {'flag':'a'}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('Saved!');
    });
 }
```

usage:

```
appendText('some text here');
```

My issue is that it's not adding the text to a new line at the end of the file content but everything is being added as a single line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append to a file in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node)

Comment: Works just fine on Unix-type OS'es, but remember that on Windows, EOL consists of two characters (`\r\n`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use appendfile() method instead of writeFile() like this and use \r\n instead of just \n.

```
 const fs = require('fs');

function appendText(text) { 
fs.appendFile("test", `${text}\r\n`, function(err) {
  if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("The file was saved!");
});

}

appendText("hello");
```