# Writing a JSON file

Tags: bots, discord.js, fs

So I am writing a json file, and when i write 2 users to a file, user B replaces user A
It should be:

```
{
    "user": {
        "user": "user1",
        "id": "id"
    },
    "user": {
        "user": "user2",
        "id": "id2"
    }
}
```

But Instead it just replaces user1 with user2.

Code:

```js
    if(command === "add"){
        let mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first()
        var user = mentionedUser.username
        var jsonData = {
            users:{
                user: user,
                id: mentionedUser.id
            }
        }
        fs.writeFileSync("./config.json", JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4), err => {
            if(err) throw err;
            message.channel.send("ID Pushed")
        })
```

Comment: You can't have two keys with the same name. Use array of users.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, that by using the same name, i.e. `user`, you overwrite the old value, instead of adding a new one.

Comment: @user6528273 so how would i make it override it?

Comment: _Use array of users_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default mode of fs.writeFileSync is to overwrite the complete file. You can use [appendFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options) or you set an option in [fileWriteSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to append the new text:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('config.json', JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4), {flag: 'a'}, err => {...});
fs.appendFileSync('config.json', JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4), err => {...});
```

You can do it also asynchronously with [appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) or [fileWrite](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback). There is also a nice [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node).

**EDIT**:

You can also import the file. Then you can create the object and attach it to the data structure. At the end you can write the result back to the file.

Comment: Could i just do
    "IDS": {
        "id": "id1",
        "id": "id2"
    }
?

Comment: What do you mean? What are you gonna do with it? You can simply write it into the file.

Comment: Basically I have *add command, so when I run it for example. *add Nicholas, it adds his id into the JSON file, and if I want to run the same command again *add Swirls, it will replace his id with mine

Comment: But the name of the user is the same?

Comment: Its not, It replaces the user aswell.

Comment: Well, you just overwrite the file and ignore the current content. For this reason you have to append the content and not replace it. You can do this with the methods mentioned above. Otherwise you can also read the JSON file and add the object and write it back to the file at the end.

Comment: I never used `fs` so its kinda hard for me to understand

Comment: At the end of your code snippet you use fs to store the data in the file.

Comment: But can I add a new id after `id1` for ex. `"IDS": {"id1", "id2"}` it adds `,` after the first ID and adds second id

Comment: Yes. There are three possibilites as described above: You can use the `appendFileSync` method, the `fileWriteSync` method with flag a or you can read the complete json file, add the new object and store the new content.