# Node js how to append a file in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

My current code is something like this.

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.appendFile('log.txt', 'new data', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // append failed
  } else {
    // done
  }
})
```

But it creates a new file outside the folder. How do i make it edit the log.txt file inside my folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to append to a file in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node). There is an answer to [reuse the file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459476/how-to-append-to-a-file-in-node/43370201#43370201)

Comment: `'log.txt'` create the file in the current working directory. `inside my folder?`  is that folder always the folder in where the file is located in which this code is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **__dirname**

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/log.txt', 'new data', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // append failed
  } else {
    // done
  }
})
```

Comment: Just as a note:  don't use `__dirname + '/log.txt'` use `path.join(__dirname, 'log.txt')` instead to combine two or more path pices.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use `path.resolve()` to get the absolute path.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.appendFile(path.resolve('log.txt'), 'new data', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // append failed
  } else {
    // done
  }
})
```

Comment: `path.resolve('log.txt')` and `'log.txt'` should in this case result int he equivalent path that is used.